# Simple Logical Error

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and mysql, so please tell me where am I wrong.

Here is my php file :

```
<?php
$c=mysql_connect("localhost","sanjay","");
if(!$c)
{
    die("Error in connecting to database");
}
else
{
    print("Success");
}

$e="CREATE DATABASE db1";
if(!mysql_query($e,$c))
{
    print("Error Creating Database");
}
else
{
    echo "Database Created";
}
mysql_select_db("db1",$c);

$e1="create table t1(id int,firstname varchar(15),lastname varchar(15),age int)";
if(!mysql_query($e1,$c))
{
    echo "Error creating table.";
}
else
{
    echo "table created";
}
?>
```

I get the following output -

```
SuccessError Creating DatabaseError creating table.
```

What am I doing wrong? And what should be the correct code for the same?

Comment: your SQL credentials don't seem to have access rights to create a database... check out what [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) tells you

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Is user "sanjay" granted rights to create **database**? Quite unlikely.

Comment: Give in all the error statements, `" . mysql_error();` instead of `";`.

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages.

Comment: Why did people rate down this question? Its my first time. Anyways, @Madara Uchiha, thanks for the links. Will start on PDO now.

Comment: @WebnetMobile, how to check whether the user has the rights or not and if not, how to grant the same?

Comment: @Exorcist: Glad I could be of assistance. Also, downvotes on a question usually indicate that the community finds your research efforts insufficient. This problem could have been solved with a little debugging and digging into the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see something wrong with your code, so i think the problem will be in **access rights** given to account. You should [modify mysql access rights](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) and `Grant` the user rights to **CREATE** (which is a privilege for both: database & table creation)